# How to get template ID of an item with glass.mapper?

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

Is there a way to check the template ID of a Sitecore item with glass mapper?

My business logic would do the following:

1. Get the context item
2. If the context item has specific template it is OK
3. If it has a different template, then find another item with that template 
   according to some business rules which also check the template

I would like to use the `SitecoreContext` class, described here: http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/ISitecoreContext

My code looks like this:

```cs
var context = new SitecoreContext(); 

var currentItem = context.GetCurrentItem<MyModel>();

if(HasCorrectTemplate(currentItem))
{
   return currentItem;
}

return GetFallbackItem();
```

I don't really want to customize Glass Mapper for this, since it seems to me it should be a basic feature to check the template ID.

I can only think of using some kind of tricky query for this and I didn't find documentation about an other possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```cs
[SitecoreType(EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template, TemplateId = "{ID}")]
public class MyModel
{
    ...
```

Here is the description of the `EnforceTemplate` property:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Forces Glass to do a template check and only returns an class if the item
///             matches the template ID or inherits a template with the templateId
/// 
/// </summary>
public SitecoreEnforceTemplate EnforceTemplate { get; set; }
```

With the `EnforceTemplate` property set Glass Mapper will check to see if the item being mapped matches the ID of the template defined by the `SitecoreType` attribute. If it does then it returns the mapped item otherwise it skips it.

Answer (score 7):

You can also add the `SitecoreInfoType.TemplateId` attribute to a property on your model which Glass will then map to the TemplateID of the item.

```
//Returns the template ID of the item as type System.Guid.
[SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateId)]
public virtual Guid TemplateId{ get; set; }
```

You can then check the template id against your item

```
if(currentItem.TemplateId == {guid-of-template-to-match})
{
   return currentItem;
}
```

The solution from @Maras is cleaner but it depends on the set up of your templates and may depend on whether you are using Code Generation templates using TDS for example.

Comment: Thanks. This actually also answers my original question, but I have decided to to use Marek's solution since it fits my use case better.